# Sequelize generating new tables and populating based on amount

Tags: mysql, sql, database, orm, sequelize.js

So I have a table like this

```
CouponId CouponCode CouponQty
1         ABCD      200
2         XYZD      100
3         QWER      200
```

And I want to generate a new table of individual coupons with their own IDs, so from this table, I would like to create a new one like this:

```
SingleCoupon CouponId(FK) 
1            1
2            1
...200       1
201          2
202          2
...300       2
```

Is this supported in sequelize?

Comment: Do you want to create a new table and fill generate records in it based on the mentioned table using Sequelize?

Comment: @Anatoly yup, is that possible in sequelize?

Comment: It's all about migrations and seeders. A migration is used to change DB structure and a seeder to fill DB by data when all migrations are already applied